# MongoDB: Map Reduce and REST-Api (Sleepy mongoose)

Tags: mongodb, rest, mapreduce

I am currently trying to do a MapReduce operation with a REST-Api (Sleepy Mongoose) on a MongoDB collection. Unfortunately, I haven't been successful yet.

My map function is :

```
function() {
    emit( this.id, {count: 1} );
 }
```

My reduce function is :

```
function(key, values) {
    var result = {count: 0};
    values.forEach(function(value) {
      result.count += value.count;
    });
    return result;
  }
```

I have tried requesting Sleepy Mongoose like that :

```
curl --data 'cmd={"mapreduce" : {"ns":MyCollection, $map="the code of my map function", $reduce="the code of my reduce function", $out="{inline:1}"}}' http://localhost:27080/myDB/_cmd
```

Unfortunately, i got a "Couldn't parse JSON" error.
I guess im not properly defining the different parameters.

Does someone succeeded doing a MapReduce operation with Sleepy Mongoose ?

I would be very thankful for any help / examples !

Comment: It's better to just send the fields you want to do the map, reduce function and the output instead of sending the actual JS functions. Is not as flexible but better and more secure than having the API accepting any JavaScript code